# Speeding up a form fill submission with email response in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, email, sendmail, contact-form

I'm incredibly new to PHP, so I'll try and be as clear as possible. Through a bit of trial and error, I created a simple form on a website I manage where people can provide a few bits of information (about four lines total). In turn, I will receive an email using ()mail with the information, which I intend to use for remarketing purposes.

The problem? It takes a good 20-30 seconds for the person who filled out their info to be taken to the Thank You page. I still end up receiving the email, but people are definitely not going to wait around for the Thank You page to load before closing the window. This is obviously not good if I'm planning on tracking conversions.

Any suggestions? A friend suggested I set up a MySQL database to collect the info, but that's way beyond my level of expertise. Are there alternatives that can help?

Many thanks.

Comment: Email timing issues != Setting up a database. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If the form submits to PHP you could use an AJAX script of which runs the PHP page. You can setup BeforeSend to show a div that simply says "Loading please wait..." and the user is more likely to wait. I'm not saying this is the best solution but its one.

AJAX Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submitBtn').click(function() {
                var variable1=$("#variable1").val();
                var variable2=$("#variable2").val();
                var dataStr = 'variable1='+variable1+'&variable2='+variable2;
                if($.trim(variable1).length>0 && $.trim(variable2).length>0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "process.php",
                        data: dataStr,
                        beforeSend: function(){ $("#submitBtn").val('Loading Please wait...');},
                        success: function(data){
                            if (data!="success") {
                                $("#submitBtn").val('Submit')
                            } else {
                                window.location.href = "http://example.com/thankyou";
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I've provided you with an AJAX example above. In the PHP script you simply need to get it to echo "success" if the email is sent. If the script ends and nothing is sent back or something else is echo'd then it will set the submit button back to "Submit".

I recommend you create a div below the submit button of which is empty by default or not visible but if the AJAX fails it is shown.